Do we want a Chinese Blog?
I was thinking, in order to improve our community commitment and involvement, we could set up our own blog.
SE sites do not have a blog by default but we can request one. I ask you to read this blog entry, which is related to this topic.
Keeping in mind that we should post there at least once a week (not necessarily the same person), the questions I'd like to you answer are:

Do you think a blog will help this site in terms of users numbers and visits?
Would you participate in the blog along with other users?
What topics should we cover? The site's topic? The site itself? 


I think it's a great idea, but feel bad because I probably won't be able to participate, spare time is a female canine animal :(

How is this idea going?

@trideceth12 It's not going at all.

(Hi from the future!  Blogs in general turn out to be a mistake: it's like creating a second site to compete with the Q&A.)

I think this is a necessity to drive traffic to our site and would be a real bonus if done correctly. I am more than willing to commit to providing posts on a rotating schedule.
The problem is, this requires someone with time and enthusiasm to drive it: Firstly, to get it up and running and then to keep it going for at least 6 months. Although the blog is a group thing it needs someone to be the glue to get it off the ground and then hold it together.

List of participants
The topics would be both Chinese and the site's technical aspect. Note that the blog is going to start only if at least 8 people will sign. But the more, the better! If you're unsure of what is this blog going to be, feel free to comment.
People who are willing to write an article now and then (regularly but with turns):

Bring on the Blog
I think a blog is a great idea. It could be used to highlight the rapidly expanding number of online/offline resources for folks learning Chinese. This would dilute the pollution of the CLSE with questions about resources. Furthermore a blog might enable additional features to add value to CLSE (audio, video outlets to assist learners).

A real party in Beijing is more attractive to me :)
